# Getting Error: redirect_uri_mismatch The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback did not match a registered redirect URI

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-bigquery

I'm getting this error while trying to run my application...

```
The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback did not match a registered redirect URI
```

In google API console i have registered my redirect urls

```
Redirect URIs:  http://localhost:8080/
```

And in the client_secrets.json also i'm using the same as redirect url
I'm following this tutorial
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/dashboard#addoauth2

Edit:

I just made some changes to the existing code

Now the

```
redirect URIs in API console is     http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback
```

And here is  my app.yaml

```
application: hellomydashboard
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /oauth2callback
  script: oauth2client/appengine.py

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

Now though its not showing any error but it displays a blank page.

Here is my main.py

```
from bqclient import BigQueryClient
import httplib2
import os
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from oauth2client.appengine import oauth2decorator_from_clientsecrets

# Project ID for project to receive bill.
# During limited availability preview, there is no bill.
# The value should be your quoted Client ID number 
# which you previously recorded from code.google.com/apis/console

# REPLACE THIS NUMBER WITH YOUR CLIENT ID
PROJECT_ID = "My Project ID"  #i just replaced dat
DATASET = "samples"
TABLE = "natality"

# CLIENT_SECRETS, name of a file containing the OAuth 2.0
# information for this application.
CLIENT_SECRETS = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'client_secrets.json')

http = httplib2.Http(memcache)
decorator = oauth2decorator_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS,
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery')

bq = BigQueryClient(http, decorator)

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    @decorator.oauth_required
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("Hello Dashboard!\n")


application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
   ('/', MainHandler),
], debug=True)

def main():
   run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So according to main.py if everything is fine it must print Hello Dashboard but it isn't

Comment: Try adding this: self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain' on the line before:
self.response.out.write('Hello Dashboard!')

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You will actually need to add the following to your redirect URIs:

```
http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback
```

Also, you may need to append a trailing `/` if the above doesn't match:

```
http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback/
```

Comment: @jade And just to be sure, you set this up as a Web Application in the console, correct?

Comment: @jade For right now you are following the tutorial step-by-step?

Comment: @jade Looking at the question you just asked (about `app.yaml`), did you have it properly configured?

Comment: i have updated my question as u said.Now the error is not showing up but i'm not getting the expected output.And when i tried with the trailing / thing as http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback/ it shows the same error

Comment: @jade This shouldn't make a difference, but I've usually specified the 'final' handler as `- url: /.*` (instead of `- url: .*`). When you see the blank page, what is the URL?

Comment: It's also worth noting that when you update the dev console, it can take about 20 minutes to catch up.  I had everything right, and couldn't figure out why I was still getting this error.

Comment: Wow. The trailing slash was indeed a problem. Thanks Google! It's bad enough that you can't provide a proper JavaScript library (with an NPM package), but you'll also be very pedantic about a trailing slash.

Answer (score 3):

using google openId I configured this

Redirect URIs:  http://domain.com/authenticate/google

on https://code.google.com/apis/console, if you must create a app if you don't have one, note that must match entirely the url

Answer (score 1):

In main.py functions main class add `(decorator.callback_path, decorator.callback_handler()),` and remove

```
- url: /oauth2callback 
    script: oauth2client/appengine.py
```

from app.yaml.

PS: You might get DownloadError if you have some proxy-configuration/webcontent-filter. If you disable these configurations or deploy it on Google Server, it will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

seems like google tries to match url with being case-sensitve cause when i tried it with **/Authorize** and **/authorize**, it gave me `redirect_uri_mismatch` error for first one but worked for latter one

someone try and let me know if i m wrong

Comment: The path part of web URLs is case sensitive so that seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

In main.py file,

in the part where you create a wsgi application

under `application = webapp.wsgiapplication(`

add a handler

```
(decorator.callback_path,decorator.callback_handler()),
```